# remove package from CTAN

Tags: ctan

I have a package on CTAN that was created as a demo and is not usefull anymore since other packages have a much better functionality. I do not want to support this package and therefore want to remove it from CTAN.

What is the process to remove a package from CTAN?
The only way I could find is to upload a new version without any package and comment to remove the package.

Comment: I think if you contact CTAN by email they can remove it for you or at least move it to the obsolete branch and change its status to unmaintained.

Comment: simply write the CTAN team. They will do whatever you want to do with your package (remove completly, change to unmaintained, move to obsolete ...)

Comment: The above comments are correct. I have done it that way.

Answer (score 16):

*(copied from comments)*

You can contact the CTAN team by email. They will do whatever you want to do with your package (remove completely, change to unmaintained, move to obsolete...)